# Fine-tune inception network 2 times (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, computer-vision, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to run flowers_train.py script from here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception/inception

to fine-tune the inception network on the flowers dataset. The difference is that I want to save a checkpoint and then run the flowers_train.py script again, but now restoring the previous saved checkpoint. I noticed that using this restorer again:
restorer = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)

gives me high loss in the first steps. So do I need to use restorer = tf.train.Saver() ?

I also noticed that the provided checkpoint file is 434,9MB, but the checkpoint I am saving is 389,9MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is variables_to_restore? If it does not include the last layer, then yes, you will see a higher loss and a smaller file size.

Comment: It includes the last layer because I am setting fine_tune argument to False. More specifically, I am training for 1000 steps and the loss is descending. When I want to restore and train again for 1000 steps the loss is higher from the previous last steps and then it's descending again. I tried to use normal restorer = tf.train.Saver() which restores all variables and I think it works because loss is not again high in the first steps.

Comment: This probably means the last layer is not getting saved.

Comment: Eitherway, tf.train.Saver() always is "the safest" way right? I mean it can't be wrong using this restorer.

Comment: The file size is smaller probably because of my final layer. The provided checkpoint contains 1000 classes in the output but my network contains only 2. Thanks for your time.